# F# : Is it okay to use mutable .Net List to add elements to the same list

Tags: .net, f#, immutability, mutable

Inside a loop I'm adding a new element to a list that I need in the next iteration, for that I use the mutable .Net `List<T>`.

`F#` encourages to use immutable collections in general, and It seems that I can't achieve what I want using immutable `list` or `seq`.

Is it acceptable to keep using the mutable .Net `List<T>`, or it's encouraged to use only immutable ones ? if so how could I achieve that ?

My code is little bit long and complex, so let's consider this pseudo F# code :

```
let children = new List<node>()
let bestBranchEntropies = entropiesSuchAs data.Rows parents
//Finding the best children for the best parent
bestBranchEntropies |> Seq.iter (fun bestBranch -> let attribut = IGetTheAttributByMaximumGainHere
                                                   //Creating one of the children in every iteration
                                                   let node = {
                                                                 content = attribut;
                                                                 branch = Some(fst bestBranch);
                                                                 children = None;
                                                                 isLeaf = false;
                                                              }
                                                   //Considering it a child
                                                   children.Add node

                                )
                       //After having all the children
                       let children' = children |> Seq.map (fun child ->  {
                                                                            content = child.content; 
                                                                            branch = child.branch; 
                                                                            children = //recursive call here to do the same work above (getting children again, yeah it's a tree)
                                                                            isLeaf = child.isLeaf;
                                                                          })

                       Some(children')
```

Comment: "Acceptable" is very subjective. Having said that: Acceptable? Most likely. Necessary? Most likely not. Faster to use mutable? Unclear. If you give more context, you will get better answers. How are you building up the list? How are you using it?

Comment: F# has a special type abbreviation for the mutable list type, so it can be ok to use it.

Comment: There is almost certainly an immutable alternative available to you, if you provide us with some context, we can probably explain how.

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer  I added some code

Comment: .Net List is called [ResizeArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.resizearray%5B't%5D-type-abbreviation-%5Bfsharp%5D) in F#. Sometimes mutable collections can be faster, especially Arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is certainly no need for a mutable list (if your pseudo-code fully reflects the problem). Consider the following:

```
let children = 
    bestBranchEntropies 
    |> Seq.map (fun bestBranch -> 
        let attribut = IGetTheAttributByMaximumGainHere
        //Creating one of the children in every iteration
        {
            content = attribut;
            branch = Some(fst bestBranch);
            children = None;
            isLeaf = false;
        }
    |> Seq.toList
children 
|> Seq.map (fun child ->  
    {
        content = child.content
        branch = child.branch
        children = //recursive call here to do the same work above (getting children again, yeah it's a tree)
        isLeaf = child.isLeaf
    }
)
|> Some
```

The first `Seq.toList` can be skipped, and you could use pipes all the way through. From your pseudo-code, it looks like the whole second loop can be safely merged with the first loop actually?

Comment: I suppose the commented-out bit about a recursive call in the second loop is the tricky bit.

Comment: Well possible - but we can only work with what's here :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's not very clear from your pseudo-code, but I understand that the real question you are asking is "can I use a mutable list instead of an accumulator when traversing a tree structure?".

I'd say it's fine, provided that:

1. The mutable object is local to the function and can't be otherwise accessed and tampered with,
2. It's purpose is clearly marked with comments, so that future maintainers won't trip on it when refactoring the code (and incorrectly assuming the mutable object to be immutable).

It certainly saves a lot of time that would need to go into writing a proper tail-recursive `fold` for your tree (which is of course an option as well, see [this blog post series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/reference-cells)). And even if you end up writing a fold, it's a fair choice for prototyping your approach first.

*As a side note, I prefer using [ref cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/reference-cells) + immutable collections rather than mutable collections for this purpose. The extra syntax required to mutate a ref cell makes it abundantly clear what is going on, as opposed to calling `Add` on a mutable list.*

Comment: And to add here that immutable lists are really surprisingly performant, and beat the mutable list in quite a few cases.